# Datediff function resulted in an overflow for two date Minute Diff (Without DateDiff_Big)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL 2008/2012.

Query to calculate Minute Difference between two dates.

```
select DATEDIFF(mi, '9999-08-03 04:20:00.000', '2005-05-22 03:45:09.530')
```

Error:

> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

Note : DateDiff_Big not support this version.

Is there any other way to get result. without using DateDiff_Big

Comment: What do you mean by "`DateDiff_Big not support this version`"? DateDiff_Big works great for this case it will return -4204542275

Comment: Why we are testing it with a date that doesn't exist or so future(9999-08-03) . Is this realistically possible..? Hope this article helps (https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/Stretching+Date+Range+Limits+on+the+DATEDIFF+and+DATEADD+Functions+in+SQL+Anywhere)

Comment: @RonenAriely: ["SQL Server (starting with 2016)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql).

Comment: Sry @JeroenMostert, I did not notice the tag 2008 :-)

Answer (score 1):

So you use a smaller unit and do some arithmetic.  But I presume you mean:

```
select datediff(minute, '2005-05-22 03:45:09.530', '9999-08-03 04:20:00.000')
```

Normally, one wants the difference to be positive (although that is not related to the answer).

```
select (convert(bigint, datediff(day, '2100-08-03 04:20:00', '9999-08-03 04:20:00.000')) * 60 * 24) +
    datediff(minute, '2005-05-22 03:45:09.530', '2100-08-03 04:20:00')
```

Comment: The only problem with this expression is constructing it, because `DATEDIFF` counts interval crossings, not actual distances. Using an obvious constant like `2100-01-01` for the intermediate won't work without applying an additional correction. `+ datediff(minute, CONVERT(DATE, '9999-08-03 04:20:00.000'), '9999-08-03 04:20:00.000')` should do it, then `2100-01-01` will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Does this fit your needs

```
DECLARE @DT1 datetime = '9999-08-03 04:20:00.000'
DECLARE @DT2 datetime = '2005-05-22 03:45:09.530'
select --DATEDIFF_BIG(mi, @DT1, @DT2),
    CONVERT(BIGINT, DATEDIFF(DAY, @DT1, @DT2)) * 24 * 60
     + CONVERT(BIGINT, DATEDIFF(mi, CONVERT(TIME(7), @DT1), CONVERT(TIME(7), @DT2)))
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

try this type to get Minutes Different

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, DATEDIFF(HOUR, '2005-05-22 03:45:09.530', '9999-08-03 04:20:00.000')) * 60
```

Answer (score 0):

[DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) has a limit that depends on what time element is used.
Because it can only return a number that fits in an INT.

> For a return value out of range for int (-2,147,483,648 to
>   +2,147,483,647), DATEDIFF returns an error. For millisecond, the maximum difference between startdate and enddate is 24 days, 20 hours,
>   31 minutes and 23.647 seconds. For second, the maximum difference is
>   68 years.

For minutes that appears to be 4083 years.

So then limit for minutes would be in the -4083 years to 4083 years range.
Then you could wrap the `DATEDIFF` in a `CASE WHEN` that checks if it's in that range.

And let it default to the DATEDIFF in hours * 60.
It'll loose some minutes for the default, but that might still be better than returning a NULL.

```
SELECT dt1, dt2,
DATEDIFF(year, dt1, dt2) AS diff_years,
DATEDIFF(hour, dt1, dt2) AS diff_hours,
CONVERT(BIGINT,
 CASE 
 WHEN DATEDIFF(year, dt1, dt2) BETWEEN -4083 AND 4083 
 THEN DATEDIFF(minute, dt1, dt2)
 ELSE CONVERT(BIGINT,DATEDIFF(hour, dt1, dt2)) * 60
 END) AS diff_minutes
FROM (VALUES 
 ('9999-08-03 04:20:00.000', '2005-05-22 03:45:09.530'),
 ('6083-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
 ('2000-01-01 00:00:00.000','6083-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
 ('0001-01-01 00:00:00.000','9999-12-31 00:00:00.000')
) q(dt1, dt2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
SELECT 
        CAST(DATEDIFF(hour, '9999-08-03 04:20:00.000', '2009-05-22 03:45:09.530') AS BIGINT)* 60+ 
        DATEDIFF(mi, CONVERT(TIME, '9999-08-03 04:20:00.000'), 
        CONVERT(TIME, '2009-05-22 03:45:09.530'))+60;
```